# How can I convert LAC and Cell ID to Latitude and Longitude?

Tags: php, google-maps, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I'm working on my first project in PHP which is to be able to display the location of a tracker on Google maps. I'm doing this based on LAC (Location Area Code) and Cell ID, and I need to convert these into Latitude and Longitude. How can I do this conversion? I've been researching this for a while without any luck.

Comment: If your question is programming language agnostic - why did you mention php and js and didn't mention any geo-related tags?

Comment: Is it possible there isn't a straightforward way? Possibly neither of those things actually correspond meaningfully to a latitude and longitude, and you'd have to simply have a list of LACs and cell IDs and which L&L coordinates they correspond to - or have the help of a third party service willing to provide such a list, e.g. via an API.